# Making Outlook server side rule using C#

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, rules

I have a strange question. I made a rule for Outlook. It is very simple rule. If there is specific word in Subject then move email to another folder. We also have Exchange server. And I would like this rule to work on a server side. The thing is, that when I am creating this same rule manualy it gets to the server. But if I am creating this rule programmaticaly, then OWA is telling me that this is Outlooks rule(and it is not working when Outlook is closed).  But if I will go to the Outlooks rules and press to that rule which was created programmaticaly (Change>Finish>Apply) then server will undesrand it as server side. How can I programmatically press the Apply button(Like I woult do it manually)? Because it seems like only Apply button tells server that it can be the server side rule. so the code is:

```
ruleName = FolderName;
                    session = app.Session;
                    store = session.DefaultStore;
                    rules = store.GetRules();

                    if (!RuleExist(ruleName, rules))
                    {
                        rule = rules.Create(ruleName, Outlook.OlRuleType.olRuleReceive);
                        ruleConditions = rule.Conditions;
                        subjectTextRuleCondition = ruleConditions.Subject;
                        subjectTextRuleCondition.Text = new string[] { "TEST" };
                        subjectTextRuleCondition.Enabled = true;
                        ruleActions = rule.Actions;
                        moveRuleAction = ruleActions.MoveToFolder;
                        moveRuleAction.Folder = INPRIS1_2;
                        moveRuleAction.Enabled = true;

                        //ruleActions.DesktopAlert.Enabled = true;

                        rules.Save(true);
```

Thanks advance.

After lots of testing I discovered that if I seperate the folders creating and rule creating then rules are made server side.
How it was: I created the new Outlook folders and then in the same button I added the rules. After that rules were only Outlook sided. 
How it is now: Firstly I create folders(with first button). And then with second I am creating rules. And then srever sees them server side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call update for server. `ExchangeService.UpdateInboxRules(IEnumereable<RuleOperation>, bool)`
**But beware:**

> When you call the UpdateInboxRules method, EWS deletes client-side send rules. Client-side send rules are stored on the client in the rule Folder Associated Information (FAI) Message and nowhere else. EWS deletes this rule FAI message by default, based on the expectation that Outlook will recreate it. However, Outlook can't recreate rules that don't also exist as an extended rule, and client-side send rules don't exist as extended rules. As a result, these rules are lost. We suggest you consider this when designing your solution.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.updateinboxrules?view=exchange-ews-api

Comment: I dont understand how it works. There is material on C++. But how can I implement it in C#?
I am trying that way `ExchangeService.UpdateInboxRules(IEnumerable<CreateRuleOperation>, false); `But I think that I do not get the idea of it. And getting error: ` Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Suppression State
Error CS0119 IEnumerable<CreateRuleOperation> is a type, which is not valid in the given context `